# I am getting an error on program: "unsupported format string passed to list.__format__"

Tags: python, python-3.x

The sample output I am supposed to mimic is:

```
Student ID  Grades
203942      88, 78, 83
236732      90, 78
9874        78
29746       79, 90 
75893       82, 80 
352418      77, 88, 84
13563       90, 89, 92
```

This is the code I have:

```
grade_book = {
                203942: [88,78,83],
                236732: [90,78],
            9874: [78],
                29746: [79,90], 
        75893: [82,80], 
        352418: [77,88,84],
        13563: [90,89,92] 
}

print ("{:<15} {:<15}".format("Students_id","Grades"))
for key, value in grade_book.items():
    print ("{:<15} {:<15}".format(key,value))
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why I am getting this error and if they can help me debug this. Thank you in advance.

New Code:

```
grade_book = {
                203942: [88,78,83],
                236732: [90,78],
            9874: [78],
                29746: [79,90], 
        75893: [82,80], 
        352418: [77,88,84],
        13563: [90,89,92] 
}

print('{:<15}'.format(', '.join(map(str, ["Students_ids" , "Grades"]))))
for key, value in grade_book.items()[0]:
    print ("{:<15} {:<15}".format(key,value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `{:<15}` formatter on a list:

```
print('{:<15}'.format([1, 2]))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

You will need to create a string first, either with `str(...)` or `.join`:

```
print('{:<15}'.format(str([1, 2])))
# '[1, 2]         '
```

or

```
print('{:<15}'.format(', '.join(map(str, [1, 2]))))
# '1, 2         '
```

Applying to your code:

```
for key, value in grade_book.items():
    print("{:<15} {:<15}".format(key, ', '.join(map(str, value))))
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error that says: "'dict_items' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @Endlessmitch Can't reproduce. **Update** your  question with the current code you are using which causes the new error

Comment: Just edited the question to show the new code. Not sure if I did it right, its my first time using this technique

Comment: I'm not sure why you decided to change your code to `grade_book.items()[0]`. My answer does not  provide this solution

Comment: Someone commented that earlier so I thought I would try it out. Im just confused on where to go from here

Comment: Well, you only need to change one line, and my answer shows you exactly how to do that